# How to add Square Brackets into Sorted Array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Expected Output:
Sorted Array in Ascending Order:
[1, 2, 3, 6]
My OutPut
Sorted Array in Ascending Order:
2 4 6 8

```
def partition(arr,low,high):
   i = ( low-1 )
   pivot = arr[high]
   for j in range(low , high):
      if arr[j] <= pivot:
         i = i+1
         arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
   arr[i+1],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[i+1]
   return ( i+1 )
# sort
def quickSort(arr,low,high):
   if low < high:
      # index
      pi = partition(arr,low,high)
      # sort the partitions
      quickSort(arr, low, pi-1)
      quickSort(arr, pi+1, high)
# main
arr = []
n = int(input("Enter no ofelements"))
print("enter elements")
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
    arr.append(ele)
print("Unsorted Array")
print(arr)
n = len(arr)
quickSort(arr,0,n-1)
print ("Sorted Array in Ascending Order:")
for i in range(n):
   print (arr[i],end=" ")
```

**Please let me know How i add Square Brackets into my Sorted Array.**

Comment: `print(arr)` without any loops, also use `for i in arr: print(i)` if you want it that way instead of using `range` to index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can replace the last two lines :

```py
for i in range(n):
   print (arr[i],end=" ")
```

by this :

```py
print(arr)
```

Output :

```
Enter no ofelements4
enter elements
2
4
3
1
Unsorted Array
[2, 4, 3, 1]
Sorted Array in Ascending Order:
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So the code looks like :

```py
def partition(arr,low,high):
   i = ( low-1 )
   pivot = arr[high]
   for j in range(low , high):
      if arr[j] <= pivot:
         i = i+1
         arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
   arr[i+1],arr[high] = arr[high],arr[i+1]
   return ( i+1 )
# sort
def quickSort(arr,low,high):
   if low < high:
      # index
      pi = partition(arr,low,high)
      # sort the partitions
      quickSort(arr, low, pi-1)
      quickSort(arr, pi+1, high)
# main
arr = []
n = int(input("Enter no ofelements"))
print("enter elements")
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
    arr.append(ele)
print("Unsorted Array")
print(arr)
n = len(arr)
quickSort(arr,0,n-1)
print ("Sorted Array in Ascending Order:")
print(arr)
```